# SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'ListId' of undefined or null reference

Tags: development, javascript, jquery, edit-form, script

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection, now when the user edit the properties of the page he will be redirected to the following page :-

[image]

so i wanted to hide all the fields except the Name and title, so inside our testing server i edit the page then i added the following code snippet :-

```
<script>

$('#formTbl tr').filter(function () 
{
return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name|Title/i);
}).remove();

</script>
```

where it hide the unwanted fields. now i did the same steps on our live server but the script raised the following error:-

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'ListId' of undefined or null reference 
>       EditForm.aspx, line 1230 character 1

so can anyone advice on this please ?

Comment: It seems there is some other script error on the page. Remove you custom script and see what is causing this error.

Comment: if i remove the custom script no errors  will be raised...

Comment: can you adivce more on this ? where i need to add this ?

Comment: I added it as an answer. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formTbl tr').filter(function () 
    {
        return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name|Title/i);
    }).remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks using your code i was able to hide the unwanted fields , but i am getting this error now :-SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'AllowWebParts' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Ok instead of `.remove`.. try `.hide()`

Comment: using .hide() worked well, but now i am 100% confused , as my original script worked well on the testing server , but it did not work on the live server, so what could be the reason behind this ? second question, why using .hide instead of .remove solve the second problem ?

Comment: Error says null reference.. This happens when object is not found.. In your case `remove` might have cause this.. These where all guess and luckily it worked. Not sure about why it happened only in Live.

Comment: now i move your code to the testing server and it worked ..